# Pandas Dataframe mean functino not working

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill in the `nan` values inside my dataframe with the mean of each column, but I found out that the `df.fillna()` function is returning the same dataframe because there mean function returns an empty series whenever I call the function like so: `df.fillna(df.mean())`. I'm having the same issue with `df.std()`, but `df.sum` works. Am i missing something or formatting my dataframe incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: Problem is `NaN`s are strings, not numeric, so solution is converting columns to numeric.

Comment: According to the pandas documentation they were just able to use np.nan and replace it. So i don't understand why it doesn't work the same. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html

Comment: yes, you can do it. But first convert values to numeric.